# How to store a List of strings in a TextFormField

Tags: flutter

**How to properly assign a List to a textformfield OnSaved**

```
class _ProductsState extends State<Products> {
  List<String>? products;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 80,
        child: TextFormField(
          onSaved: (input){
            products=input; // A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable 
                                                       // of type 'List<String>?'
          },
        ),
)
);
}
}
```

I want whatever i type in the textfield gets stored in the List of products like this [0]['Whatever i type'],[1]['sdsdw']

Comment: change to `products.add(input);`

Comment: I'm getting Error: Unexpected null value. @Jungwon

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. `products!.add(input!);` You have to prefix it with `!` because it is null safty.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says:

> A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List?'

Your `products` variable is declared as a `List<String>?`, but you're then trying to assign an optional string value to it, but you can't assign a string to a list.

What you *can* do is add the input value to the list:

```
products.add(input);
```

Or you can declare `products` to be of the correct type:

```
String? products;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will be solved.

```
List<String>? products;
    
    return Scaffold(
        body:Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 80,
          child: TextFormField(
            onSaved: (input){
              products!.add(input!); 
            },
          ),
        )
    );
```

Comment: I double checked the null safety issue before you added the solution, but i always get a null value regardless.

Comment: Could you please update the source of the question?